# Error Exception Handling Error, Too many redirects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exception, error-handling

I tried to create custom error pages and view them while my environment is still "Development", so in my Startup.cs file I change my code into :

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
       //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
         app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");
 }
```

Then I create an **Error** Action in my `HomeController.cs` and a **PageNotFound** action.
So my `HomeController.cs` now looks like :

```
[RouteAttribute("/Home/Error/{code?}")]
public IActionResult Error(int? code = null)
{            
       if(code.Value == 404)
       {
           return View("PageNotFound");
       }
       return View();
}

public IActionResult PageNotFound()
{
      return View();
}
```

Actually this works great except this redirects too much. For example, If I would like to go to a page which will return status code of 404, then what happens in my debug is, Error action calls 5~ times and then suddenly it returns my `View("PageNotFound)`. And this is **not the only** issue, main issue is, after every action call(No matter if it returns an **Error** or not) my debugger goes to **Error Action**, repeats this 5 times then suddenly returns the main page content... What is happening here, what am I missing? Someone please help me.. Thank you!

Comment: I test the code and it works well.It is very likely that it's being called multiple times due to images not being found on said page,then it will lead to 404.You could press F12 in browser to check the console.

Comment: Please follow the standard way to handle custom errors. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: @XingZou oh I got it.. I'm gonna take care of those errors shown in my browser.

Comment: @habib Okay I will, thank you for the link..